# How to redirect root and only root via htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect only my root to another url, but maintain all the /sub/directories where they belong (and redirect)

example:

mysite.com/1 redirects to somewhere
mysite.com/admin opens a page

i want mysite.com/ to redirect to mysecondsite.com and only this with a 301 redirect using htaccess

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://mysecondsite.com/ [L,R=301]
```

If you don't need to check for the old domain (for example, if the directory where your .htaccess is placed is only used by the old domain) you can remove the second line.

Comment: In my case, I needed to redirect traffic to mysite.com/ but not foo.mysite.com so had to add a regex to line 2: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [NC]` to ensure the match was for the exact host

Comment: It is more efficient to check the URL-path in the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ (as in @DaveForgac's answer), instead of using an additional _condition_ to check the `REQUEST_URI` server variable.

Comment: This will also redirect root with parameters: this.com/?a=123

Comment: To exclude URLs with certain parameters, add:  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !my_parameter=
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134384/htaccess-to-redirect-one-domain-to-another-only-if-no-parameters-are-provided

Answer (score 43):

If you mean you'd only like to redirect "/" to another domain, this will work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

This only matches the domain's root with nothing after it so it will only redirect the domain name without a filename specified.

Comment: A slight variation worked for me. Added to the bottom of my htaccess, after all other rules invoked, I just wanted to render a welcome page to anyone visiting my root domain (without any subdomain):
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(subdomain1|subdomain2)\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /welcome.php [NC,L]

Comment: This will also redirect root with parameters: this.com/?a=123

Answer (score 18):

This should work just fine:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ https://example.com/
```

Comment: This would be preferable (to the existing answers) if you are not already using mod_rewrite for other redirects.

Comment: maybe a 302 would be a better

Comment: This will also redirect root with parameters: this.com/?a=123

Answer (score -4):

A shorter solution:

```
Redirect 301 / http://mysecondsite.com/
```

Comment: This will NOT do what jardel wants. It will redirect ALL pages rather than just the root.