# Redirecting based on URL via .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I saw this: [How to redirect root and only root via htaccess?](https://serverfault.com/questions/58762/how-to-redirect-root-and-only-root-via-htaccess) and it's close, but not quite.

I am in the middle of rewriting a site, and would like to be able to send users from:

```
http://myfullurl.com
```

to:

```
http://mylandingpageurl.com
```

While retaining the ability to test the site at:

```
http://myfullurl.hostingprovider.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mod_rewrite like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myfullurl\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mylandingpageurl.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, does exactly what it needed to do. Thanks!