# How do I redirect only the root page to another subdomain via htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to redirect only my top level domain eg. domain.com to sub.domain.com. The inner pages of the domain should not be redirected.

I followed the following link: [How to redirect root and only root via htaccess?](https://serverfault.com/questions/58762/how-to-redirect-root-and-only-root-via-htaccess)

But when doing a search on my site, the query was appended to the sub domain like:

sub.domain.com/?q=product where it should have been domain.com/?q=product

My current htaccess already has to following that has rewritten:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(png|gif|ico|swf|jpe?g|js|css)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php?sef_rewrite=1 [L,QSA]
```

What do I add to achieve the behaviour stated above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just below the `RewriteEngine On`, add:

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://sub.domain.com [R=301,L]
```

If I'm reading correctly, it sounds like you want to keep the query string.  But if you want to delete it, you'd use:

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://sub.domain.com? [R=301,L]
```

**Edit:**  To only redirect the `/` page in the case that it has no query string, use:

```
RewriteCond ${QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^$ http://sub.domain.com [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I tried `RewriteRule ^/$ http://sub.domain.com? [R=301,L]` but it is not redirecting.

Comment: @komirad My mistake, it's in an htaccess file - use `^$` instead of `^/$`.

Comment: It redirected but the query string on form submit didn't work. Some javascript widgets failed too.

Comment: @komirad Can you clarify whether you wanted to keep or remove the query string in the redirect?

Comment: The query string need to be kept. Search form on sub.domain.com when submitted should go to domain.com/?q=dress

Comment: @komirad Remove the `?` from your configuration, then; as I mentioned in my answer, it's for if you want to remove the query string.

Comment: There's a misunderstanding. The query string needs to be kept but it should not be appended to the redirected sub domain. With your solution, I got this **sub.domain.com?q=product**. Instead, I want **domain.com?q=product**.

Comment: @komirad Ok - so you want to keep the URL in the user's browser as entered, but send them the content from `sub.domain.com`?  Is that correct?

Comment: No. I only want to redirect the "home page" domain.com to sub.domain.com(or use rewriting if that's possible). Anything else such as domain.com/about or domain.com/?q=product should not be affected. Is that possible?

Comment: @komirad Ah, I understand now!  See edit.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this statement:

```
ServerName mydomain.tld
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mydomain.tld [R=301,L]
```

You can also reuse all parameters by this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mydomain.tld$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Tried `RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mydomain.tld$1 [R=301,L]` but the query string is appended to the redirected sub domain instead of the top level domain.